# Trying to convert epoch code field (string type) to timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to convert from epoch code to timestamp, in legacy SQL it's working fine and in standard SQL I'm getting an error. 
Field name custom_field_6 (string type field) represent epoch time and I want to convert it to timestamp (in standard SQL)

In legacy SQL I did the following: 
`select 
      custom_field_6 as custom_field_6,
      timestamp(custom_field_6) as custom_field_6_convert 
FROM [yellowhead-visionbi-rivery:yellowhead_prod.affise_conversions]`

[The query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Njb.png)

In standard sql:

`select 
 custom_field_6 as custom_field_6,
 cast(custom_field_6  as date) as custom_field_6_converted
FROM`yellowhead-visionbi-rivery.yellowhead_prod.affise_conversions``

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM4FW.png): "invalid date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below id for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  custom_field_6, 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(custom_field_6 AS INT64)) custom_field_6_convert
FROM `yellowhead-visionbi-rivery.yellowhead_prod.affise_conversions`
```

you can test it using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1540051185' custom_field_6 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1540252572' 
)
SELECT 
  custom_field_6, 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(custom_field_6 AS INT64)) custom_field_6_convert
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row custom_field_6  custom_field_6_convert   
1   1540051185      2018-10-20 15:59:45 UTC  
2   1540252572      2018-10-22 23:56:12 UTC
```

Comment: This is the error I get:

Query Failed
Error: Bad int64 value: {installed_at}
Job ID: yellowhead-visionbi-rivery:US.bquijob_70505117_1673a6cfa50

Comment: Provide example of your data